# Best way to re-initialise a compiled Theano function

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano

I want to refresh my compiled MLP model in Theano as I want to repeat a model with different hyper-parameters.

I am aware that I can redefine all the functions, however, compile time for each function is significant.

I want to define a function which will refresh the models of their

The following code below is shown for demonstration.

```
    # construct the MLP class
    classifier = MLP(
        rng=rng,
        input=x,
        n_in= n_input,
        n_hidden=n_hidden,
        n_out= n_output)

    cost = (classifier.negative_log_likelihood(y)
        + self.l1 * classifier.L1
        + self.l2 * classifier.L2_sqr)

    gparams = [T.grad(cost, param) for param in classifier.params]

    updates = [(param, param - self.lr * gparam) \
        for param, gparam in zip(classifier.params, gparams)]

    train_model = theano.function(
        inputs=[index],
        outputs=cost,
        updates=updates,
        givens={x: self.xTrain[index * self.batchSize: (index + 1) * self.batchSize],
            y: self.yTrain[index * self.batchSize: (index + 1) * self.batchSize]})
```

My instinct suggests that I can simply re-define the `MLP()` class without any implications on the other compiled functions.

Is this correct?

I was thinking that if this is the case I could define a function of `MLP.refresh()` which re-instanciated parameters for each component of the `MLP()` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear how the `MLP` class is working but you can re-use a previously compiled computation as long as the number of dimensions of the shared variables does not change.

In the following example the `compile_model` function creates a simple neural network with randomly initialized parameters. After training with those parameters, the shared variables are re-initialized to new random values, but this time the network's hidden layer size is increased. Despite this change in size, the original training function is re-used.

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt


def compile_model(input_size, hidden_size, output_size, learning_rate):
    w_h = theano.shared(numpy.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size).astype(theano.config.floatX))
    b_h = theano.shared(numpy.zeros(hidden_size, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
    w_y = theano.shared(numpy.random.randn(hidden_size, output_size).astype(theano.config.floatX))
    b_y = theano.shared(numpy.zeros(output_size, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
    parameters = (w_h, b_h, w_y, b_y)
    x = tt.matrix()
    z = tt.lvector()
    h = tt.tanh(theano.dot(x, w_h) + b_h)
    y = tt.nnet.softmax(theano.dot(h, w_y) + b_y)
    c = tt.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(y, z).mean()
    u = [(p, p - learning_rate * theano.grad(c, p)) for p in parameters]
    trainer = theano.function([x, z], outputs=[c], updates=u)
    tester = theano.function([x], outputs=[y])
    return trainer, tester, parameters


def refresh_model(parameters, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    w_h, b_h, w_y, b_y = parameters
    w_h.set_value(numpy.random.randn(input_size, hidden_size).astype(theano.config.floatX))
    b_h.set_value(numpy.zeros(hidden_size, dtype=theano.config.floatX))
    w_y.set_value(numpy.random.randn(hidden_size, output_size).astype(theano.config.floatX))
    b_y.set_value(numpy.zeros(output_size, dtype=theano.config.floatX))


def main():
    input_size = 30
    hidden_size = 10
    output_size = 20
    learning_rate = 0.01
    batch_size = 40
    epoch_count = 50

    trainer, tester, parameters = compile_model(input_size, hidden_size, output_size, learning_rate)
    x = numpy.random.randn(batch_size, input_size)
    z = numpy.random.randint(output_size, size=(batch_size,))
    print 'Training model with hidden size', hidden_size

    for _ in xrange(epoch_count):
        print trainer(x, z)

    hidden_size = 15
    refresh_model(parameters, input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
    print 'Training model with hidden size', hidden_size

    for _ in xrange(epoch_count):
        print trainer(x, z)


main()
```

Comment: do they have to be instantiated as `theano.shared` ?

Comment: Depends on what you think the alternative would be. You almost certainly want to use shared variables.